# Silex: how to connect several 3rd-party libraries?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, silex

I'm trying to inject a 3rd-party tool into my custom class in Silex. Then i plan to replace this tool with another library at some point. To conform to DI principles, to decouple my class and libraries, I'm going to specify an interface those tools must implement. And type hint an interface in my custom class constructor. This will help me to avoid any changes to my class. Like this

```
class MyCustomClass 
{
    private $tool;

    public function __construct(MyCustomInterface $tool)
    {
        $this->tool = $tool;
    }
}
```

To register those 3rd-party libraries, i have to create service provider for each one of them. Then it seems i need some kind of adapters to make these tools conform to a contract MyCustomInterface states. It turns out for every 3rd-party instrument I have to manage 2 extra classes (provider and adapter).

My questions are:

- Am I getting DI concept completely correct?
- Is it possible to simplify this solution?
- Is Silex able to manage this situation with 'adapters'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are getting the DI concept right. If you don't want to refactor your whole code (well the code that uses your library) every time you change your library then the adapter is the way to go: you define a specific API with the interface which every adapter must implement. This way you code can safely call the interface methods without having any knowledge of the implementation behind. So IMHO this is the way to go, you're right here again (but I think your the solution in the Silex context can be simplified, and yes, Silex can manage this, any other modern framework should as well).

To simplify your proposed solution I wouldn't create a different provider for each implementation. The provider is what bonds your library with the Silex, you just need to tell the provider which adapter (implementation) must use and you can do that with a parameter (see note at the end of the code sample). So I would go with something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Acme\MyCustomInterface; // This is your library interface

class MyCustomLibraryServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['some_dependency'] = $app->protect(function() use ($app) {
           // do whatever to create a new instance of this dependency
        });

        $app['another_dependency'] = $app->protect(function() use ($app) {
           // do whatever to create a new instance of this dependency
        });

        $app['my_service'] = $app->protect(function () use ($app) {
            // assuming your adapter has 2 dependencies.
            $myService = new $app['my_service_class']($app['some_dependency'], $app['another_dependency']);

            if (!$myService instanceof MyCustomInterface) {
                throw new \RuntimeException("The 'my_service_class' parameter must implement MyCustomInterface!");
            }

            return $myService;
        });
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
    }
}
```

Then when you are creating your $app instance (you can create as much adapters as you want):

```
<?php
//...
use Acme\MyCustomLibraryServiceProvider;

//...
$app->register(new MyCustomLibraryServiceProvider(), [
    'my_service_class' => "Acme\MyCustomLibraryAdapter1"
]);
```

Notice that this solution assumes that each adapter will have the same dependencies. If this is not the case, you'll need to create another provider for each adapter, but if you don't want to do that, keep reading :-)

If you want to simplify this even more, take into account that you *don't* need to create a provider at all. If your library has no dependencies or has only 1 or 2, you can create your service directly in the same file where you create your application instance (IMHO the provider is only useful if the code to create your service is heavy):

```
<?php
//...
use Silex\Application;
use Acme\MyCustomLibraryAdapter1;

$app = new Application();
//...
$app['my_service'] = $app->protect(function() use ($app) {
  $dep1 = new WhatEver();

  return new MyCustomLibraryAdapter1($dep1);
});
```

This solution is less elegant but simpler (you need to change the code that creates your service for each adapter).

Comment: Thank you a lot for this descriptive answer. You gave me the idea of wrapping up the logic with this whole adapters stuff into a provider. That's nice, i've never thought about that way. I'll definitely use it!

Comment: IMHO that's what the Silex (well Pimple) providers are for :-)

Comment: yeah, but i just kept dependencies instantiating outside of the provider (or service registering), and your solution makes more sense to me. It's logically correct to keep it in one place i think.